# Flask application factory pattern init empty database, not my model on ubuntu

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, server

I want to create a flask application using the application factory pattern, I want to separate my logic and my models. The server starts without errors, but after I migrate my database it creates an empty db.

I'm currently using ubuntu, in windows it creates the db properly.

**__init__.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from .extensions import db
from flask_migrate import Migrate

migrate = Migrate()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
    from .models import File
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    return app
```

The **models.py:**

```
from .extensions import db

class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    audio_path = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    original_txt = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    corrected_txt = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'File %r' % self.audio_path
```

**extensions.py** is where I define my SQLAlchemy db:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Why is it not creating the database from my model?

Answer (score 0):

this just works for me:

you need to declare db = SQLAlchemy() inside the models.py file, not in the extensions file, and then in the **init**.py file import db from models, init the db class by: db.init_app(app). and migrate.init_app(app, db).